# Store image file in jQuery key/value

Tags: jquery, key-value

Trying to store an image file in a key/value pair and am having trouble getting it to show the image file. Right now it just prints out the actual HTML markup as text.

```
var data = { 
  someKey: [
    {
      image: "<img src='image.jpg'>",
      text: "Some text"
    },
  ]
};
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Answered my own question below.

Comment: How do you try to show it?

Comment: Using handlebars.js
    
`<td>{{image}}</td> 
<td>{{text}}</td>`

Comment: Ughh, just figured it out...i don't know why, but you asking me how i'm showing it made it click. so, thanks? :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question because I figured it out.

Also forgot to mention I'm using `handlebars.js`.

Storing the file name as a value and then passing it as a filename in the HTML markup.

**jQuery**

```
var data = { 
  someKey: [
    {
      image: "imageName",
      text: "Some text"
    },
  ]
};
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="{{image}}.jpg">
```

**Output**

```
<img src="imageName.jpg">
```